# Get column header names and Related table header names in Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where I need to get the column headers and the headers of all related tables in my entity framework core 5 project. I have tried using the below code

```
    var columns = typeof(Asset).GetProperties()
                .Select(property => property.Name)
                .Where(c => c == "Id" || !c.EndsWith("Id"))
                .ToList();

    return headers.ToList();
```

This code gets me the header names but I need the related table headers as well. I have not found any information on how to do that in EF core 5.

any help would be appreciated ..

Update: Just to give more information on the issue

I have the main Assets table that has a relationship to five other tables using foreign key constraints. I am trying to get the headers from all six tables into a single list.

The code that I have posted is only getting the names from the properties of the asset class but I need the names for all six tables.

The 5 related tables contains an Id and a name column like CategoryName, ManufacturerName, etc.

How can I get what I am looking for through entity framework core 5 or do I have to find a solution outside entity framework?

my Asset Class

```
namespace Home_Inventory_BL.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Asset
    {   // Int property that gets/sets id
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets Name
        [Required]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key
        //Int property that gets/sets category id
        [DataMember]
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets Manufacturer id
        [DataMember]
        public int? ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets model
        [DataMember]
        public string Model { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets serial number
        [DataMember]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        // String property that gets/sets purchase place
        [DataMember]
        public string PurchasePlace { get; set; }
        //Int property that gets/sets quantity
        [DataMember]
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        // Datetime property that gets/sets acquired date
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        // Float property that gets/sets purchase price
        [DataMember]
        public double? PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        //Float property that gets/sets current value
        [DataMember]
        public double? CurrentValue { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets condition id
        [DataMember]
        public int? ConditionId { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Int property that gets/sets location id
        [DataMember]
        public int? LocationId { get; set; }
        // Datetime property that gets/sets retired date
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? RetiredDate { get; set; }
        //String property that gets/sets description
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        // Collection of asset files
        [DataMember]
        public ICollection<AssetFile> AssetFiles { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        [DataMember]
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        [DataMember]
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        // Navigation Property
        [DataMember]
        public Condition Condition { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        [DataMember]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core mapping information is stored in `Model`.

```cs
var et = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Asset));
var storeObject = StoreObjectIdentifier.Create(et, StoreObjectType.Table);
var columnNames = et.GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.IsKey()).
  .Select(c => c.GetColumnName(storeObject))
  .ToList();

// continue with navigations
var navigations = et.GetNavigations();
```

Comment: The above code is only producing the column name of Id. The where clause above in my post was filtering out foreign keys but leaving the asset id name. When I take out the where clause I is still does not give me the column names of the related tables. For more information I have updated my post.

Comment: So add Asset class to question. Anyway you have enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: I have  shared my asset class. Still new to this hence my questions how am I to return the navigations with the column names? when I try to return the navigations I get a conversion error message a little more help would be welcome.

Comment: Have you missed GetNavigations from my answer?

Comment: I see it just not understanding how to return it with the other data is all.. still new to C# so it is a learning process .

Comment: I do not understand this at all, I can get the table names from the navigation but I still do not see how I can get the column names from it. I haven't found anything related to using navigation to get column names.